# В чем рекурсивная ошибка javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь добиться, чтобы при нажатии на область psewdophoto нажимался input , который внутри него, но браузер выдает ошибку в консоли(вроде, как я понимаю, зацикливание):

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="psewdophoto">
        <input type="file" class="post_photo">
    </li>
    <li class="psewdophoto">
        <input type="file" class="post_photo">
    </li>
    <li class="psewdophoto">
        <input type="file" class="post_photo">
    </li>
    <li class="psewdophoto">
        <input type="file" class="post_photo">
    </li>
    <li class="psewdophoto">
        <input type="file" class="post_photo">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$('.psewdophoto').click(function(event){
        $(this).children('.post_photo').click();
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: А если поменять местами строки: `$(this).children('.post_photo').click();` и `event.preventDefault();`?

Comment: @Eleferen а что это даст, хотя бы в теории?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да мог бы оставить ответ

Comment: @PavelMayorov https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема во всплытии события `click`. Вызывая `click` у дочернего элемента в обработчике клика родителя, при всплытии ты опять попадаешь в обработчик родительского элемента и все по новой.

Если вывести `event.target` можно заметить, что всегда выводится `input`.

```js
var i = 0;
$('.psewdophoto').click(function(event) {
  if (i++ < 5) {
    $(this).children('.post_photo').click();
    console.log(event.target);
  }
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
li {
  border: solid 1px green;
}

input {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="psewdophoto">
    <input type="file" class="post_photo">
  </li>
  <li class="psewdophoto">
    <input type="file" class="post_photo">
  </li>
  <li class="psewdophoto">
    <input type="file" class="post_photo">
  </li>
  <li class="psewdophoto">
    <input type="file" class="post_photo">
  </li>
  <li class="psewdophoto">
    <input type="file" class="post_photo">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Для решения можно добавить обработчик для `input` в котором запретить всплытие с помощью [`.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

```js
$('.psewdophoto').click(function(event) {
  $(this).children('.post_photo').click();
  event.preventDefault();
});

$('input').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
li {
  border: solid 1px green;
}

input {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="psewdophoto">
    <input type="file" class="post_photo">
  </li>
  <li class="psewdophoto">
    <input type="file" class="post_photo">
  </li>
  <li class="psewdophoto">
    <input type="file" class="post_photo">
  </li>
  <li class="psewdophoto">
    <input type="file" class="post_photo">
  </li>
  <li class="psewdophoto">
    <input type="file" class="post_photo">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: А почему собственно при возникновении события клика у ребёнка это же событие возникает и у родителя?

Comment: @ArturHan [всплытие событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling)

Comment: @ArturHan, это такая схема работы событий в js. Однако некоторые события не всплывают :)

Answer (score 0):

При клике на элементе также срабатывает событие и на родителе, об этом следует не забывать.

```js
$('.psewdophoto').click(function(event){
    $(this).children('.post_photo').click((function(e) {
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    })
 );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="psewdophoto">
        <input type="file" class="post_photo">
    </li>
    <li class="psewdophoto">
        <input type="file" class="post_photo">
    </li>
    <li class="psewdophoto">
        <input type="file" class="post_photo">
    </li>
    <li class="psewdophoto">
        <input type="file" class="post_photo">
    </li>
    <li class="psewdophoto">
        <input type="file" class="post_photo">
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Ваш код не эмулирует клик на input, а вешает на него обработчик.

Comment: Ну и плюсом к тому что код работает неправильно, добавлять всё новые и новые обработчики события на каждый клик по родительскому элементу - плохая затея

Comment: @Regent Проблему я понял, но вот с решением поторопился...